# Please explain this delete top 100 SQL syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I want to do this:

```
delete top( 100 ) from table order by id asc
```

but MS SQL doesn't allow order in this position

The common solution seems to be this:

```
DELETE table WHERE id IN(SELECT TOP (100) id FROM table ORDER BY id asc)
```

But I also found this method [here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2009/05/22/UPDATE-and-DELETE-TOP-and-ORDER-BY---Part2.aspx):

```
delete table from (select top (100) * from table order by id asc) table
```

which has a much better estimated execution plan (74:26). Unfortunately I don't really understand the syntax, please can some one explain it to me?

Always interested in any other methods to achieve the same result as well.

EDIT: I'm still not getting it I'm afraid, I want to be able to read the query as I read the first two which are practically English. The above queries to me are:

```
delete the top 100 records from table, with the records ordered by id ascending
delete the top 100 records from table where id is anyone of (this lot of ids)
delete table from (this lot of records) table
```

I can't change the third one into a logical English sentence... I guess what I'm trying to get at is how does this turn into "delete from table (this lot of records)". The 'from' seems to be in an illogical position and the second mention of 'table' is logically superfluous (to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete` command takes several similar forms, as the `from` keyword is optional, and the deletion table can be specified separate from the query selecting the records:

```
delete table where ...

delete from table where ...

delete table from <query...>

delete from table from <query...>
```

The idea with the last two ones is that you can first define which table to delete from, then you can specify a query that picks out the records to delete. The query can join in other tables, that's why you would need to separately define from which table to delete.

The query that you found just uses a subquery to pick out the records to delete.

Comment: I can't match up one of your 4 syntaxes with the third example which reads to me as "Delete table from subtable table". Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: @Patrick: You can add the optional `from` to your query (the difference between the 3rd and 4th form above) to make it read more logically. I adjusted the forms above to be more descriptive.

Comment: @Patrick: The query could be described in english as "delete all records from table matching it's records in (this lot of records called 'table')." Note that the last "table" in the query is an alias, not the actual name of the table.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried "DELETE tbl_audit FROM (SELECT TOP ( 1 ) * FROM tbl_audit order by id asc) tbl_blah" thinking it would create tbl_blah and then delete the records in blah from tbl_audit but it deleted all the records in tbl_audit! I understand aliasing as in select x as y from ..., but still don't really understand this

Answer (score 5):

This is explained well [here](http://sqlcat.com/msdnmirror/archive/2009/05/20/fast-ordered-delete.aspx)  (The article talks about using a view but I presume the same logic must apply to your query if you are getting a better execution plan)

> the first one reads the “deleted”
>   portion of the table twice. Once to identify
>   the rows to delete and then once more
>   to perform the delete.

The second one avoids this.

**Edit** This seems to be more a question about syntax. The syntax for delete is [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx).

The relevant bit is

```
DELETE 
    [ FROM ]
    { <object> | rowset_function_limited 
    }
    [ FROM <table_source> [ ,...n ] ]
```

Your query is

```
delete alias 
from 
    (select top (100) * 
     from table 
     order by id asc) alias
```

You are using a derived table so need the `FROM <table_source>`. You are omitting the first optional FROM.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking to do is a technique called a *Fast Ordered Delete*.

Take a look at the following Blog post: [Performing Fast SQL Server Delete operations](http://www.johnsansom.com/index.php/2009/05/fast-sql-server-delete/)